# Queue-trigger Azure Function: Queue messages processed more than once

Tags: c#, function, azure, queue

I have an HTTP-trigger Azure Function that adds a message to the queue: outputQueue.AddAsync(myMessage); Then the Queue-trigger Azure Function is triggered. It adds 100 messages to the same queue. Each one of those 100 messages is dequeued by this function and processed. This processing takes about 5-7 minutes. My functionTimeout is 10 minutes. Sometimes (in 10% of the calls) the same message is being dequeued amd processed twice and even more, thought the previous processing of this message was successful. Also I paid attantion that each such redundent dequeue happens about 10 minutes after the previous dequeue of the same massage (seems to be related to my functionTimeout of 10 minutes). So it looks like after the processing is done the function is not ended and hence not deleted from the queue, which causes another instance to dequeue it.

When I look at the Failures section of Application Insights I see that approximately for 1K operations I have about 10 WebExceptions and 2 TimeoutExceptions.

WebException:

Message: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
Failed method:
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoExceptiond
FormattedMessage: An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.

TimeoutException:

Message: The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout. The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout.
Failed method: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync
FormattedMessage: An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.

I have try..catch in my Function entry point, but probably those 2 exceptions don't go to the catch block.

My host.json is as follows:

```
{
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": 1000,
      "visibilityTimeout": "01:00:00",
      "batchSize": 8,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 4
    }
  }
}
```

When I set "batchSize": 2 and "newBatchThreshold": 1 I have less redundant dequeues, but more instances are created (I know this by logging the IP of the server of every Azure Function call). If I have more servers that process different messages then my static data is less re-used betwen instances.

Also note that I've set the "visibilityTimeout" to 1 hour (I tried 30 minutes as well), but looks like this value is completely ignored and the message becomes visible after 10 minutes.

Any idea how I can avoid duplicate processing of the same messages? I'm thinking about writing the message info to DB after the successful processing and on every dequeue of a message check if this message was processed, say, within 1 hour from now and if so, not to process it again. Another option I'm thinking about is setting "maxDequeueCount" to 1 (I have a restore mechanism if some messages won't be processed at all due to some real failure).

BTW, those 10% of redundant processings don't cause functionality issues, but I still want to improve the performance.

Comment: your messages are not complete because the function times out tho they are visible again. You should try to break down your function into smaller functions. Then you can use durable function for example or having mutiple queues than will chain the work you have to do. If you can't breakit down, maybe you should  change the app service plan ?

Comment: Consider using durable functions for the long running task at the end. It’ll allow you to break the function up within the same execution path and keep within acceptable time limits.